# How to use DataContext.ExecuteCommand and get the executed stored proc return value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, return-value

In a c# project, I call a stored procedure as follows:

```
System.Data.Linq.DataContext dataContext = MembershipContext.GetContext(connectionString);
int returnValue = dataContext.ExecuteCommand("EXEC usp_SomeProcedure {0}, {1}, {2}", param1, param2, param3);
```

However, ExecuteCommand returns the number of rows affected, and not my stored procedure return value. What would be the easiest way to get this value. I need this because the SP returns 0 on success and a positive int value if an error occurred.

For now, the stored proc uses RETURN to output its return value. However, I could change this for a SELECT or I could also use an output parameter if required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to set the CommandType to CommandType.StoredProcedure in order to get the return value from your stored proc. See the accepted answer here: [Getting return value from stored procedure in ADO.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309213/getting-return-value-from-stored-procedure-in-ado-net)

Comment: I used the example given on the page you referred too, and it is working. I am not using the DataContext anymore as Serg Rogovtsev suggested. +1 to both of you!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `DataContext` for calling SPs if you don't need Linq2Sql mapping functionality. Just use `SqlCommand` as [down.with.the.bass shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11654837/1105881).