# ExecuteNonQuery always returns -1

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, executenonquery

I have created a stored procedure for deleting record. In this stored procedure I am first checking for the usage of data which I am going to delete. If it is being used, then the stored procedure will return -2 otherwise it deletes the record.

But the problem is that even the record exists its return -1 instead of -2. I have also set the `NOCOUNT OFF` but don't know where is the problem.

I know this question is already answered by setting `NOCOUNT OFF` but its not working for me

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDeletePIDNumber]
    @Id int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    if(exists(select * from tblBills where PID = @Id))
    begin
        return -2
    end
    else
    begin
        Delete from HelperPIDNumber 
        where Id = @Id
    end
END

public int DeletePIDNumber(int Id)
{
        try
        {
            int result = 0;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connection))
            {
                var cmd = new SqlCommand("spDeletePIDNumber", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);

                conn.Open();
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you are trying?

Comment: post the code where you're using `.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: and add some return value below `Delete ,,,,` statement.

Comment: I did that return value below delete but didn't worked

Comment: @mcNets questioin updated

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` doesn't return the result of the procedure you're calling. Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Instead of relying on the return value you can map an output parameter to get the return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection **and returns the number of rows affected**.

Having `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in your procedure explicitely tells to SQL Server **not** to return a row count. In that case the return of the `ExecuteNonQuery` function is -1.

Also if the procedure does not affect any rows, it will not return a row count either even if `NOCOUNT` is `OFF`. In that case the return will also be -1.

---

What you appear to want to do is get the `return value` of the stored procedure. You will not get that from the result of `ExecuteNonQuery`. Please refer to this question on StackOverflow: [Getting return value from stored procedure in ADO.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3309213/243373)

Answer (score 2):

Generally `ExecuteNonQuery` will return number of affected records. It will return `-1` in two cases:

1. When `SET NOCOUNT ON` has been set. From your code, its clear, you have `SET NOCOUNT OFF` and so this is not an issue at your case.
2. If number of affected rows is nothing, it will return `-1`. In your case, it looks like you are checking the data exists from one table `tblBills` and delete from another table `HelperPIDNumber`. So there is more chance there will be no matching record and nothing deleted.

Please check the **point # 2** above.

```
if( exists(select * from tblBills where PID = @Id))
begin
    return -2
end
else
begin
    Delete from HelperPIDNumber where Id = @Id
end
```

Comment: In a nutshell the return value of the ExecuteNonQuery is a system reserved value, you should not try to interfere with that. If you want to send back custom value to the C# code from your SP, use an output parameter and extract the value.

Comment: @Geethanga That's not my code :-) I have copied the user's code and highlighted the possible issue from the particular piece of code

Answer (score 0):

use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` instead of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` as`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` return only the number of affected rows and not the value you are selecting.

Comment: Nope. From the documentation: `Executes the query, and **returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query**. Additional columns or rows are ignored.`. This is not the same as the return **value**.

Comment: `return -2` can be changed to `SELECT -1`

Comment: The OP could do that, but that is generally a bad idea. For stored procedures it is usually a good idea to have the resultset(s) returned be of the same format (ie same columns in the same order).